# How can I display the 'settings menu' in the viewfinder on the Olympus OM-D E-M5?

Tags: camera-settings, olympus, olympus-omd

I came into possession of an OM-D E-M5 with a broken screen, and I would like to tweak the menus of the camera. However, I did not succeed to bring them up in the viewfinder. Does anyone know how to access the menus in the viewfinder?

Answer (score 1):

There should be an evf/lv button near the eye piece.Keep pressing that until the evf lights up.
Alternatively you can use a mini hdmi lead and patch it through to a monitor or tv in order to get to the menu options then select evf eye control only.Set up the camera using a monitor.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem with the OM-D E-M5 Mk 2. After resigning myself to not being able to change the settings in menu (this meant setting date and time too), I found that if you hold the EVF button (fn3 on Mk 2) (looks like a curved rectangle between two vertical lines) you get an option to change "automatic vf on" to manual. On the manual setting I was able to see the menu.